# Creating an array of a linked list(of nodes)

Tags: arrays, data-structures, linked-list, nodes

I'm supposed to create this data structure of an array of a linked nodes

[image]

However, i'm not really sure how to do so, I tried to define an array of a linked list like this :

```
Node<Integer>[] arr=new Node<Integer>()[10];
```

but it says "The constructor Node() is undefined"
How do I achieve the wanted structure?
It needs to fit the input for this function :

```
 public static int numFromLists(Node<Integer> []arList)
```

Comment: which programming language? Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this (assuming you are using JAVA):

```
LinkedList <LinkedList<Integer>> arr=new LinkedList();
for(int i=0;i<=9;i++)
    arr.add(new LinkedList());
arr.get(2).add(1);
arr.get(3).add(3);
arr.get(3).add(4);
arr.get(5).add(6);
arr.get(7).add(2);
arr.get(7).add(5);
```

Comment: I am using java but I meant more of a list of nodes, in my class we call it a linked list but we use the keyword node it's just a couple of nodes created individually that are linked to one another we can't use the linked list itself, Do you know how to create it using Nodes?kind of like I did but in a way it'll work

Comment: I have a function  :                                                                             
public static int numFromLists(Node<Integer> []arList)                                        and it gets an array of a linked list of nodes so it would really help if you could show me how to create that data structure so that it'll work with my input to the function.